# Cannot yield all the rows in a table as key, value using sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, key-value-store

For some reason, I cannot iterate through all the rows in a table when I am yielding from a SELECT statement in sqlite3. When I return the result as list, I have all the rows.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong...

The code below only yields only single row if I use it somewhere outside:

```py
def items(self):
        for row in self._cursor.execute('SELECT key, value FROM dict_table'):
            yield (self.loads(row[0]), self.loads(row[1]))
```

If I wrap the return as a list, I get all the rows:

```py
def iteritems(self):
        for row in self._cursor.execute('SELECT key, value FROM dict_table'):
            yield (self.loads(row[0]), self.loads(row[1]))


def items(self):
        return(list(self.iteritems()))
```

Ideally, I want only use it as a generator as opposed to getting whole list

```py
def items(self):
        for row in self._cursor.execute('SELECT key, value FROM dict_table'):
            yield (self.loads(row[0]), self.loads(row[1]))
```

Somewhere else in the code, I just want to be able to run:

```py
for key, val in self.items():
    print(val/key)
```

### EDIT:

I also tried the following solution without any success

```py
def iteritems(self):
        for row in self._cursor.execute('SELECT key, value FROM dict_table'):
            yield (self.loads(row[0]), self.loads(row[1]))


def items(self):
        yield from (self.iteritems())
```

It also still returns me 1 row when I am trying to iterate over items

Comment: Because 1st one just iterate once hence gives first 2 rows but 2nd one iterate till the end hence giving you all the rows. Yield gives you next item in list

Comment: In 1st case, I am wrapping in a for loop. I would need to return a generator in order not to return the whole list. 

I am doing the following:

for item in self.iteritmes():
   take item and do work

But I only get two items instead of 50

Comment: Each time it is returning same rows...right?

Comment: Yes, just one row.

Comment: what’s the issue? your function yields values hence why when you wrap it in a list call it consumes the generator all at once.

Comment: Although, if my class inherits MutableMapping, I don't have to implement items() methods and I am able to get away with:

def __iter__(self):
        for row in self._connection.execute('SELECT key FROM dict_table'):
            yield (self.loads(row[0]))

Comment: @aws_apprentice 
If I don't return a wrapped function, I don't have all the rows.

Comment: yea that’s because you are yielding values, once again, using yield will return one row at a time. I suggest looking in to how yield works since based on this question/conversation you do not understand how it works

Comment: @aws_apprentice
I've added some information to the question

Answer (score 1):

All I can think of is that perhaps you are reusing the same cursor for more than one query at the same time and the earlier iterator is stopping as the cursor has been used for a later query.

To fix this you should create a new cursor for every query.

Comment: Yes, I have the same feeling because when I use the connection.execute instead of cursor.execute, it gives me slightly different results. Moreover, when I use c2 = connections.cursor() and then run the execute method, my application hangs. I am not sure what is causing it. Otherwise, I am re-using the same cursor, but all the calls are synchronous and sequential. I would expect the cursor to return different number of rows each time if I had a concurrency issue in there.

Comment: I'll try creating a cursor again, but for some reason, it does seem to hang

Answer (score -1):

This is because you are fetching the rows again and again. please try below solution

```
def items(self):
        rows = self._cursor.execute('SELECT key, value FROM dict_table')
        for row in rows:
            yield (row)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work :(

yield statement should not run execute and fetch rows again, it should come back to first statement in yield which is self.loads(row[0]), self.loads(row[1]). If it would fetch them again and again, I should be stuck in an infinite loop?

Comment: I have updated my solution. please try that. it will return one row at a time. if you want to return all the rows together the just remove for loop and return rows instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't want to return all rows as I need to return an iterable, but as generator, not as whole list. I've tried your modified solution, and when I iterate over items (for item in self.items()), I only get one item. I am puzzled :O

Comment: can you please post this code where you are iterating over items?

Comment: for k, v in self.items():
print(v/k) - nothing complicated; with your code and mine, I only get one result for some reason

Comment: I have tried both, and it is the same result. I have a suspicion that something is not kosher with the cursor.